# Collecting Flow<List> and displaying it in Compose (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-flow

Hello guys I have list of movies that I call from MovieApi.

In movieRepo I did this:

```
override suspend fun getPopularMovies() : Flow<List<Movie>>{
        val popularMovies : Flow<List<Movie>> = flow{
            while(true){
                val lastMovie = movieApi.getPopularMovies()
                Log.i("EMIT", "${emit(lastMovie)}")
                kotlinx.coroutines.delay(5000)
            }
        }
      
        return popularMovies
    }
```

In MovieViewModel:

```
init{
     viewModelScope.launch {
         repository.getPopularMovies().collect(){
            Log.i("COLLECTED", "$it")
         }
     }
 }


private suspend fun getPopularMovies()  {
    
    return repository.getPopularMovies().collect()
}
```

I know that collect gets all Movies I want, but I need to display it in my HomeScreen with viewModel when I call getPopularMovies.
I'm reading Flow docs but cant understan how this part works(news part is from Flow documentation):

```
newsRepository.favoriteLatestNews.collect { favoriteNews ->
               // Update View with the latest favorite news
            }
```

Comment: popularMovies and favouriteNews are the same thing?

Comment: latestNews is from Flow documentation

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question too actually. Curious to see if you had found out anything.
I could be mistaken in this but I would like to gain a better understanding in this so I would appreciate for other to chime in as well.


Assuming you're using targeting a recyclerview.

For non-Viewmodel collection approach, the collection has to be done in the UI layer.

In collect block, you will need to pass movie list to adapter's submitList.

But if you still want to do collection in ViewModel, you will need to create a UIState as a StateFlow. Collect the movie list into a UI state.

In UI layer, collect the UI state and access the movie list from it